# How to copy yanked text to VI command prompt

Tags: vim

I want to know if there is any way by which I can paste yanked text to the command window. For instance if I have yanked a word and I want to grep it in some location I can't simply paste the word using 'p'. However if I copy it to clipboard, Shift-Insert will paste the same thing.

Is there any tweak available which would allow me to paste yanked text to the vim command prompt?

I am using gvim on Windows.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

try to use

```
<ctrl+r>"
```

where " stands for default register.

Comment: Note that this also work in normal insert mode, not only on the command line.

Comment: If you use `*` instead of `"`, you'll get the contents of the system clipboard instead (which might be handy).

Answer (score 44):

`<C-R>"` Will paste default buffer. Alternately, you can use `q:` to open a buffer for the next command. try `:help q:`

Comment: Holy crap, `q:` is beyond awesome

Answer (score 22):

- ensure first you are in normal mode by pressing `Esc`
- once in normal mode, press `:`
- then use the keyboard combination `ctrl-r`, and then type `"`

Note: if you are yanking a full line containing relative file path, the line feed will by pasted as well ... i.e. 
`:! touch src/bash/script.sh^M`

WILL create a "funny file path" containing the "\r" if you do not remove the last `^M` ...

Answer (score 16):

To save you a step of yanking, if your cursor is on the word you want to use in Ex, use:

```
 <ctl-r><ctl-w>
```

This eschews yanking to paste into the command line; instead, one pastes the word under one's cursor directly onto the command line. E.g.:

```
:%s/<ctl-r><ctl-w>/foo/g
```

Answer (score 5):

If it is just a word that you want to copy, you can use `<C-r><C-w>`

1. Put your cursor over the word
2. Then you can type something like `:vim <C-r><C-w> *`

Answer (score 3):

You can yank to the clipboard using the `*` named buffer.  For instance, this will copy the current line to the clipboard:

```
"*yy
```

So you can copy a line using this, and then paste it with shift-insert in the commandline.

Similarly, you can paste from the clipboard like this:

```
"*p
```

Answer (score 2):

The clipboard's `+`, on Mac at least. So you'd write `"+yy` to yank a line to the clipboard, and `"+p` to paste. Though you could always use Command-C and Command-V.